# JS - object adds self to array when created

Tags: javascript, object, parameter-passing

I am trying to have an object in js add itself to a list as it is being created. I thought simply adding `this` as the parameter would have worked, but it seems to not work for some reason. How should I do this?

```
<script>
function car(make, model, year, color, owner) {
    this.make = make;
    this.model = model;
    this.year = year;
    this.color = color;
    this.owner = owner || null;
    this.to_string = function() {
        return 
            "Car: " + this.color + " " + this.year + " " + this.make + " " + this.model + "\n" +
            "Owner: " + this.owner.name;
    }
    all_cars.add(this); //<---issue
    owner.buy_car(this); //<---issue
}

var all_cars = function() {
    this.list = new Array();
    this.add = function(car) {
        this.list.push(car);
    }
    this.to_string = function() {
        var r = "";
        for (var i = 0; i < this.list.length; i++) {
            r += ((r == "") ? "" : "\n\n");
            r += this.list[i].to_string();
        }
        return "ALL CARS\n" + r;
    }
}

function human(name, cars) {
this.name = name;
    this.cars = cars || new Array();
    this.buy_car = function(car) {
        car.owner = this.name;
        this.array.push(car);
    }
    this.sell_car = function(index, buyer) {
        buyer.buy_car(this.cars.splice(index));
    }
}

var vin_254s45s8wf6a = new car("Honda", "Accord", 2007, "WHT");
var vin_45d8s3g3j8x8 = new car("Toyota", "Camery", 2009, "BLU");
var vin_9s3d4f8s5w9d = new car("BMW", "JX5", 2017, "SLV");
var vin_45s6a8d5s9g2 = new car("Lexus", "CT 200h Hybrid F SPORT", 2016, "RED");
var vin_9s3d45s8wf6a = new car("Toyota", "Navta", 2001, "GRN");
var mike = new Human("Mike Smith", [vin_45s6a8d5s9g2, vin_45d8s3g3j8x8]);
var jim = new Human("Jim Hamelton", [vin_9s3d4f8s5w9d]);
var evie = new Human("Evelyn Ma", [vin_9s3d45s8wf6a]);

document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "HI"; //all_cars.to_string()
</script>
```

Comment: `human` function begins with lowercase `h`, though called with uppercase `H`; `this.array` is not defined within `this.buy_car` at `human` function; should `vin_*`  be quoted strings?

Comment: `all_cars` is a function (or class constructor, depending on how you use it). So you can't really do `all_cars.add(...)`. What you need is create an instance of `all_cars` like this: `var my_cars = new all_cars();`. Then do: `my_cars.add(this);` inside the `car` function.

Answer (score 0):

```
var all_cars = function() {
    var x = {};
    x.list = new Array();
    x.add = function(car) {
        this.list.push(car);
    }
    x.to_string = function() {
        var r = "";
        for (var i = 0; i < this.list.length; i++) {
            r += ((r == "") ? "" : "\n\n");
            r += this.list[i].to_string();
        }
        return "ALL CARS\n" + r;
    }
   return x;
}
```

You were not returning anything .do the same for humen

Comment: That didn't seem to do anything. What did I miss?

Comment: all_cars().add(this); You forgot to call the function

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I would structure the code (I've also included fixes for a bunch of issues):

```
function Car(make, model, year, color, owner) {
  this.make = make;
  this.model = model;
  this.year = year;
  this.color = color;
  if (owner) {
    owner.buyCar(this);
  }
  this.toString = function() {
    var ownerName = this.owner ? this.owner.name : "no owner";
    return (
      "Car: " + this.color + " " + this.year + " " + this.make + " " + this.model + "\n" +
      "Owner: " + ownerName
    );
  }
}

function CarCollection() {
  this.list = [];
  this.add = function(car) {
    this.list.push(car);
  }
  this.newCar = function(make, model, year, color, owner) {
    var car = new Car(make, model, year, color, owner);
    this.add(car);
    return car;
  }
  this.toString = function() {
    var cars =
      this.list.map(function(car) {
        return car.toString();
      }).join("\n\n");
    return "ALL CARS\n" + cars;
  }
}

function Human(name, cars) {
  this.name = name;
  this.cars = cars || [];
  this.buyCar = function(car) {
    car.owner = this;
    this.cars.push(car);
  }
  this.sellCar = function(car, buyer) {
    var index = this.cars.indexOf(car);
    if (index === -1) {
      throw new Error("Trying to sell a car that I don't own!");
    }
    buyer.buyCar(this.cars.splice(index, 1));
  }
}

var collection = new CarCollection();

var vin_254s45s8wf6a = collection.newCar("Honda", "Accord", 2007, "WHT");
var vin_45d8s3g3j8x8 = collection.newCar("Toyota", "Camery", 2009, "BLU");
var vin_9s3d4f8s5w9d = collection.newCar("BMW", "JX5", 2017, "SLV");
var vin_45s6a8d5s9g2 = collection.newCar("Lexus", "CT 200h Hybrid F SPORT", 2016, "RED");
var vin_9s3d45s8wf6a = collection.newCar("Toyota", "Navta", 2001, "GRN");

var mike = new Human("Mike Smith", [vin_45s6a8d5s9g2, vin_45d8s3g3j8x8]);
var jim = new Human("Jim Hamelton", [vin_9s3d4f8s5w9d]);
var evie = new Human("Evelyn Ma", [vin_9s3d45s8wf6a]);

document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = collection.toString();
```